# Oracle NUMBER(10) columns is reported as Int64 instead of Int32

Tags: c#, oracle

I had to come back to an exiting project (hardly two months old) for a small change. I'm getting exceptions left and right on it now but it was in working condition and deployed to production and is running. The errors are pretty strange as well: It is all Oracle datatypes being read differently now. A Number(10) di column for a row was easily read as a DataRow and saved to a POCO's respective int property. But the same code is failing now.

Original code that was working before:

```
public static async Task<(OracleConnection connection, OracleDataAdapter adapter)> GetOraclePackage()
{
    try
    {
        // To satisfy async. serves no purpose.
        await Task.FromResult(0);

        if (WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.ConnectionStringBilling] == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Oracle connection string is not found in web.config");
        }

        var oraConnection = new OracleConnection { ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.ConnectionStringBilling].ConnectionString };
        var oraDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter { SelectCommand = new OracleCommand { CommandType = CommandType.Text, Connection = oraConnection } };

        return (oraConnection, oraDataAdapter);
    }
    catch (OracleException oraExp)
    {
        throw new RepositoryLayerException("Oracle error in repository's helper method GetOraclePackage() " + oraExp.Message, oraExp);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RepositoryLayerException("Error in repository's helper method GetOraclePackage() " + e.Message, e);
    }
}

public async Task<IList<BDO.AirportServiceWithTerminal>> GetAllServices()
{
    var objResult = new List<BDO.AirportServiceWithTerminal>();
    var oraclePackage = await Helper.GetOraclePackage();
    var ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        var sql = @"
                SELECT
                    s.service_code,
                    s.account_code,
                    s.service_fees,
                    s.customer_type,
                    s.period,
                    s.ser_name_e,
                    s.isvat,
                    s.vatvalue
                FROM
                    serviceinfo s
                WHERE
                        sevice_status = '1'
                    AND
                        service_fees > 1
                    AND
                        account_code IN (
                            'AB','BC','CD','DE'
                        )
                ";

        oraclePackage.connection.Open();
        oraclePackage.adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = sql;
        oraclePackage.adapter.Fill(ds, "ServiceList");

        if (ds.Tables[0] != null)
        {
            foreach (DataRow oneService in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {           
                var newTerminalService = new BDO.AirportServiceWithTerminal
                {                           
                    Code = oneService.Field<int>("service_code"),                       
                    NameEnglish = oneService.Field<string>("ser_name_e").Replace(@"""", "").Trim(),
                    Fee = oneService.Field<decimal>("service_fees"),
                    IsVat = oneService.Field<string>("isvat") == "1",
                    VatValue = int.Parse(oneService.Field<string>("vatvalue"))
                };

                objResult.Add(newTerminalService);
            }                   
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw new RepositoryLayerException("An error occurred while retrieving all services from billing system", exp);
    }
    finally
    {
        oraclePackage.adapter.Dispose();
        if (oraclePackage.connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) oraclePackage.connection.Close();
        oraclePackage.connection.Dispose();
    }

    return objResult;
}
```

And now, when it tries to cast the `service_code` to int, it fails. I tried to get the type of `service_code` as follows:

`oneService["service_code"].GetType()`

and I either get `UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "Int64" FullName = "System.Int64"}` or `UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "Decimal" FullName = "System.Decimal"}`

(Whe writing this SO question, I started to get Decimal)

Is there a way around this by doing some cast as I know the database has not been changed and I cannot just accept the new types as there are many. Same case is for decimals now reported as doubles.

Comment: `Number(10)` in general case doesn't fit `int` (`Int32`), e.g.: `9876543210` > `int.MaxValue` (`2147483647`)

Comment: 2^32 < 9 999 999 999

Comment: Use `Int64.Parse` instead of `int32`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, that would force me to update my POCO property's datatype to Int64. That is not possible. I need to know why all of a sudden, the datatypes returned from Oracle are being inferred differently in c#. And downcasting is not helping, i.e., 'Convert.ToInt32()` is not working.

Comment: Well, how would you expect a overflow to be handled? What do you expect your number to become when exceeding int.maxValue?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, it wouldn't. In fact, even int32 is too big for that number. There are only 2000 services at a time. The oldest service is moved to a storage and a new one is added. The IDs are not auto numbers.

Comment: @DoomerDGR8 the *database* can't guess that you intend to use only 2K numbers. C# doesn't know that either. If you wanted a smaller number, you should use a *different* key, eg a NUMBER(4). It looks like you are using a *10-digit business key* as the primary key. In general it's a bad idea to use business keys as primary keys because their meaning and representation can easily change for various business reasons, no matter how much the customer insists it won't. There's always an "except but that rarely happens"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I completely agree with you on this. Thing is, I have no control over the DB. It is 15 years old. I'm tasked to revamp the system and have to ensure the new SQL Server DB would be able to import all the data. I have made the new DB and it is very good in terms of data types now. But I have to ensure the existing apps are working before the VAT is implemented countrywide from Jan 2019. Only then, I can launch my new system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *general case* Oracle's `Number(10)` doesn't fit `int` (`Int32`) since `Number(10)` has a *wider range*:

```
  Type        Min Value     Max Value 
  ------------------------------------
  Number(10) -9999999999 .. 9999999999
      Int32  -2147483648 .. 2147483647
```

That's why, say, `9876543210` can be represented as `Number(10)` but not as `int` (and this is the very reason for .Net to map `Number(10)` to `Int64`). If values in the database are guaranteed to be *small enough* (and thus in fact *fit* `int`), try using `Convert`:

```
  Code = Convert.ToInt32(oneService.Field<object>("service_code"));
  ...  
  VatValue = Convert.ToInt32(oneService.Field<object>("vatvalue"));
```

Comment: This double conversion works for me. I still don't know how this happened.

Comment: @DoomerDGR8: `oneService.Field<object>("vatvalue")` reads the  `vatvalue` field *as is*; then `Convert.ToInt32` tries to convert the value read to `Int32`

Comment: Every db works fine with migration scripts and datatypes generated. But Oracle is "special". Do u suggest me to go through my entire project and replace all int32 to int 64 or add this Convert command everywhere. This is insane.

Comment: @ADM-IT: often (not Oracle alone, but Postgre, Interbase etc.) Rdbms types do not perfectly fit .net ones. If you are sure in ranges (`MyValue` is guaranteed to be less than 2 billions and that's why of type `int`) keep types but add `Convert`. In case of ids try keeping them as `string` (again put Convert) for you not to depend on mapping (int, long, guid)